# Access object properties - Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-framework-7

I have simple AJAX call. 
It looks like this:

```
myApp.onPageInit('about', function (page) {

   search_term = $$("#search_term").val();
   const key = "xxxx-xxxx";
   const nick = "https://api.xxx.xxx/" + search_term + "?api_key=" + key;

   $$.ajax({
    url:nick,
    type:'GET',
    dataType: JSON,
    beforeSend: function(){
    //myApp.showPreloader('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //myApp.hidePreloader();
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data['summonerLevel']);
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
           // myApp.alert('Account does not exist.', 'ERROR');
        }
      },
    error: function(data) {
        myApp.alert('Account does not exist.', 'ERROR');
        // ak je ovaj error, netko je dirao putanju - fajl 
    },

    }); 
})
```

When I'm trying to get properties from `data` object, every time it says undefined.

Console log: `{"id":"xxxx","accountId":"xxxx","puuid":"xxxx","name":"Data","profileIconId":3015,"revisionDate":1546082318000,"summonerLevel":37}`

Second console log: `undefined`

I tried dot notation and bracket notation, but everytime same status(undefined).
Like this:

```
console.log(data['summonerLevel']);
console.log(data.summonerLevel);
```

Any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: if they are real keys and ids in there - you should change them.

Comment: have you tried `var obj = JSON.parse(data)` then `obj['summonerLevel']`?

Comment: @palaѕн thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: If you set `dataType: 'json'` then you shouldn't have to parse it manually

Comment: @proofzy Also, in future when asking questions please try not to post original api keys and URLs to be safe.

Comment: @palaѕн allright!

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.Parse()` method and try taking the value with `object.attributename`

```
$.ajax({
url:nick,
type:'GET',
dataType: JSON,
beforeSend: function(){
},
success: function(data) {
   var data=JSON.Parse(data);
    console.log(data.summonerLevel);
    console.log(data.accountId);
},
statusCode: {
    404: function() {
    }
  },
error: function(data) {

},

});
```